# ionic - ion-nav-view not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a ionic pacakage, having multiple views. I use the route provider to navigate between different views.

app.js

```
.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/search',
        {
            controller : 'MyController',
            templateUrl : 'partials/search.html'
        })

    .when('/not-found/:className',
        {
            controller : 'MyController',
            templateUrl : 'partials/not-found.html'
        })
```

My index.html

```
  <body ng-app="MyApp">  
        <ng-view></ng-view>

      </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that the back button on my phone does not work.i.e it does not remember the history.
e.g If I go from search.html to not-found.html, when I press the back button on my phone, I expect it to come back to search.html instead it closes my app.
I looked and ionic forum and the suggest way to make back button work is to use `ion-nav-view`. If I replace `ng-view` with `ion-nav-view`, the search/not-found page are not rendering, I even tried adding the `ion-view` on the search/not-found html page.
1) Could you please suggest a way to get my back button working?

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve that, you actually need to **capture the hardware back button pressed event** and perform the navigation accordingly or You can use **ion-nav-back-button**..

1. Capture the hardware back button event :

   ```
   $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
     if (condition) {
       navigator.app.exitApp();
     } else {
       // handle back action!
     }
   }, 100);
   ```

More Details can be found [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-the-hardware-back-buttons/1505/7)

---

2. Using ion-nav-back-button

   ```
   <ion-nav-bar>
     <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
       <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
     </ion-nav-back-button>
   </ion-nav-bar>
   ```

More Details about this can be found [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/)

Answer (score 0):

`registerBackButtonAction` is already handled as part of `ion-nav-back-button` as part of the `ng-click` attribute within the `ion-nav-back-button` definition: `buttonEle.setAttribute('ng-click', '$ionicGoBack()')` , since `$ionicGoBack` executes `$ionicHistory.goBack()` which in turn handles the hardware back button. A simple change to use state configuration should work fine as below:

```
angular
  .module('app', ['ionic'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
     .state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        controller : 'MyController',
        templateUrl : 'partials/search.html'
    })
   .state('not-found', {
        url: `/not-found/:className',
        controller : 'MyController',
        templateUrl : 'partials/not-found.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/search');        
  });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">  
    <ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```